# Ugly lock screen in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 18 and have seen other people have a beautiful UI, I'm still stuck with the bulky ugly one, did I miss a configuration setting I was supposed to change?

It wont let me put a picture, so here's a link.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ubuntu-17.10-login-screen.jpg

That is my current lock screen. Yet I've seen people with much prettier login screens. Inside UI is much nicer and smoother, why is my login screen still the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have GDM set as your desktop manager. Do `sudo apt install lightdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and select `lightdm` at the package configuration window.